# In ios7 for xamarin application is not taking retina images

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios

I am developing one xamarin app and using ios7.I am having one image with LikeIconSmall.png and LikeIconSmall@2x.png.but it is not taking retina image,it is always taking nonretina images on retina phone also.Please suggest any solution.This issue is for all images in application.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to get the images. Also explain where you have stored the images (Resources folder?). Also ensure that you are actually trying all this on a Retina device or Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure the build action for your images is set to content and you are using `UIImage.FromBundle(path)` to load you image